# Prevent event handlers in an iframe from affecting the parent window/page (jump/scroll to top)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to prevent a toggle event inside an iframe from causing the parent page to jump up to the top when clicked.

The child page does not do that by itself thanks to the following code below. However, when I interact with it while inside an iframe; the same child page causes the parent with the iframe to jumps up to the top when I click on the toggle button in the child page.

I used:

```html
return false;
evt.preventDefault();
evt.stopPropagation();
```

And they work fine if I was looking at the child page by itself. However, the code has no effect in preventing the parent page from jumping to the top.

Child page code (Application Matrix PHP):

```css
.documentBody
{
    color: #808080;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.documentBody a
{
    color: #0075a0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.documentBody a:hover
{
    color: #0092c8;
}
.boxBodyArticulatedTrucks {
    display: block;
    height: 208px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url( "../assets/user-interface/articles/box/body/background/articulated-trucks.png" ) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.boxBodyArticulatedTrucks:hover
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.questionForm
{
    /*width: 587px;*/
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.questionFormBody
{
    /*background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;*/
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.btnAccordion
{    
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: url( "../assets/user-interface/articles/accordion/icons/down-arrow.png" ) no-repeat center right 20px #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<div id="articulatedTruck">
  <div class="documentBody">
    <div class="btnAccordion">
      Articulated Truck
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="questionForm">
    <div id="questionFormBody0" class="questionFormBody">
      <div style="padding-top: 26px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        1. What is the application(s)?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#chkArticulatedTruck').change(function () {
      $('#articulatedTruck').toggle(this.checked);
      parent.setArticleSize();
      return false; // Prevent page from jumping to the top
    }).change(); // Ensure visible state matches initially
  });
</script>
```

Parent page code:

```html
<iframe id="article" src="./applications/application-matrix.php" width="627px" height="500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```